# Windows 8 out of memory?

Tags: windows-8, memory

I thought that Windows 8 was supposed to be better with memory than Windows 7. So far, that is not my experience.

When I boot up my brand new laptop (Samsung NP550P5C-S03CA Intel Core i5 3210M 8GB 1TB ) , the Task Manager Performance tab tells me that I have:

8.0 Gb of DDR3 available
 of this:

3.7GB is in use, leaving 4.2GB available

3.5/25.9 GB is committed and 1.4GB is cached.

162Mb paged pool, 2.4GB non-paged.

I then go to the Details tab, and I add up the Memory used by all the processes. It comes to about 300Mb. That is 0.3GB.  So what is using up the other 3.4GB of memory???

I then load up a bunch of programs that I use concurrently - notably Firefox (with about 30 tabs), Chrome, Thunderbird, Notepad++, Filezilla and my memory consumption goes up to 4.4GB. That seems about right.

I then work on it for a number of days, hibernating in-between, and I start to get notices that I am running low of memory. The performance tab says I am using 90% or more of my memory. The committed has gone up to 31GB. But if I add up the memory usage listed in the Details tab, it comes to only about 1800MB (I notice that Firefox has gone up to about 1300MB)

So, again, where has all my memory gone?

If I then close all the programs, it doesn't help. The details tab shows little running, yet the Performance tab shows I am still out of memory?

What is using up all my memory?

The only thing that clears it, is to do a restart. Which brings us back to the top of the loop, with the same initial question - what is using up over 4GB of my memory?

I never had these problems with windows 7.

As a sidenote, Win 8 also seems to be very unstable. Frequently getting programs not responding and crashing, including Windows Explorer, which seems to have to reload itself frequently.

Oh, and my wifi connection keeps dying and then I have to run the troubleshooter to get it all running again (my wife has that same problem on her brand new Acer).

So, what gives? How do I get my new laptop to work as fast as my 4 year old Sony Vaio with Win 7 and lower specs?

Anyone got any ideas? Or is this normal for windows 8?

Comment: If you don't want your memory to be used, take it out of the computer and put it on your desk. Your system is *using* memory and you are complaining that it isn't *wasting* it? Wtf?

Comment: One problem might be that Samsung, in their infinite wisdom, decided to duplicate a basic Windows memory management feature with their "Intellimemory" feature. See [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/538151/how-to-speed-up-windows-8/538558#538558). If you have it I would recommend disabling it.

Comment: I was under the impression that I shouldn't pay attention to the numbers really because if an application needs the memory, the OS will release some memory as needed. So I can never be "low on memory" unless ofcourse I am using that memory.

Answer (score 15):

Okay, let's use some real numbers. My computer has 16 GB of RAM.

The **Performance** tab in Windows 8's Task Manager says:

[image]

- In use: **4.2 GB**
- Available: **11.6 GB**

This *in use* value matches the **Resource Monitor**:

[image]

- Hardware Reserved: 106 MB
- In use: **4462 MB**
- Modified: 7 MB
- Standby: 11788 MB
- Free: 21 MB

So, i have **4,462 MB** of RAM "in use". What is the breakdown of that 4,462 MB of RAM? Who is using it?

If we add up the *"Working Set"* of all processes from Task Manager, e.g.:

- explorer.exe: 244,936 kB
- glcnd.exe: 202,964 kB
- chrome.exe: 201,372 kB
- chrome.exe: 133,060 kB
- MsMpEng.exe: 84,568 kB
- uTorrent.exe: 70,496 kB
- Skype: 79,084 kB
- ...
- GoogleCrashHandler64.exe: 868 kB
- smss.exe: 548 kB
- System: 532 kB

We only get **2,713 MB**. i have **4,462 MB** *in use*. What is taking up the extra **1,749 MB** of RAM?

The answer is the the kernel and drivers.

- Cache Working Set: 357 MB
- Kernel Working Set: 35 MB
- Driver Working Set: 11 MB
- Paged Pool Working Set: 483 MB
- Non-paged Pool: 286 MB
- Metafile: 577 MB
- **Total: 1,749 MB**

Windows 8 uses 64% more RAM than the applications alone.

## But is that normal?

Yes. Here's a Windows 7 computer with 16 GB of RAM:

- *"In use"*: 7,276 MB
- Process Working Set: 4,214 MB  (a difference of 3,062 MB)
- Cache Working Set: 604 MB
- Kernel Working Set: 4 MB
- Driver Working Set: 7 MB
- Paged Pool Working Set: 2,426 MB
- Non-paged Pool: 0 MB

Windows 7 uses 72% more RAM than the applications alone.

### More comparisons

```
                Windows 8  Windows 7  Windows Vista  Windows XP
                =========  =========  =============  ==========
Total RAM          768 MB     768 MB         768 MB      768 MB
 In Use            682 MB     611 MB         631 MB      651 MB
  Process WS       642 MB     565 MB         
  Cache WS          24 MB      70 MB          98 MB       53 MB
  Kernel WS          3 MB       1 MB           0 MB       
  Driver WS          3 MB       3 MB           2 MB
  Paged WS          37 MB      66 MB          48 MB       18 MB
  Non-paged         27 MB      19 MB          28 MB        6 MB
```

Answer (score 11):

You have a Samsung device, so you probably have a non paged pool driver leak caused by the tag ECMC. Run [Poolmon to verify this](https://superuser.com/questions/533135/98-100-memory-use-no-process-uses-more-than-25mb/533187#533187). If this is the case and you see **intmsd.sys** which uses ECMC, uninstall the tool **Intellimem**

Answer (score 4):

From your simptoms my best guess would be that your have a memory leak in some resident programs you are using. My Windows 8 is running weeks without reboot, and does not run out of memory.

I would recommend to pay attention to individual processes that consume large amounts of memory, something must be there that eats all that RAM.

Since, as I guess, you are using new notebook with preinstalled Windows 8, I suppose you have some of the preinstalled "vendor tools", which usually tend to be some poorly written useless programs. So I would also try to turn them off, and see if it helps. Some of them could run "invisible" and run on startup, so take a time investigating that too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I just repaired the Intellimem program, i used to have 92% mem consumption now i have 25%, i guess it's back to normal.

I really don't know if windows 8 it's really a buggy operating systems, or samsung drivers are really bad and very untested.

I had several problems and issues before, with this new samsung series 7 chronos laptop with w8pro. It's really a waste of time using this OP, you have to look always for a solution on the web, i spend hours of hours of your time.

Comment: I may be missing the point, but how did you repair the program?

Comment: Your best bet is to disable Intellimem. Even if it's not apparently causing any problems right now.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8 I had this problem and found that the computer was turning the WiFi card off to conserve power.

Here is how to fix that:

1. Right click the WiFi internet access in the task bar.
2. Click **Open Network and Sharing Center**.
3. Click **Change Adapter Settings**.
4. Right-click **Wi-Fi connection**.
5. Click **Properties**.
6. Click **Configure**.
7. Click **Power Management.**
8. Uncheck **"Allow the computer to turn of this device to save power"** box.
9. Click **Okay** and close all tabs.

I hope it works for your problem.

Comment: How does this relate to his problem of memory usage?  I am completely not seeing the connection.