# Is this RAM usage normal (huge non-paged pool)?

Tags: windows-8, memory

I bought an ultrabook today. It boots extremely quickly and everything, so obviously some sophisticated techniques are involved, but I'm confused because task manager shows over 80% RAM usage when I'm only running a web browser...

After further inspection I noticed that active processes add up to over 1GB (pretty normal) and over 2GB are assigned to a non-paged pool. What does it mean? Can it be normal on an ultrabook? If not, how should I fix it?

Here's the Task Manager

[image: task manager]

UPDATE: I tried disabling every single startup program, scheduled task, also temporarily uninstalled "Kaspersky Internet Security". No luck.

Comment: How large is the non-paged pool after booting?

Comment: @Louis It's 2GB seconds after boot. If I go to the task manager as fast as possible I can sometimes see it filling up quickly.

Comment: I've just started trying to figure out what that area of memory is for, but so far I suspect that one of your device drivers has a memory leak. I would try disabling non-essential devices (network adapters, Bluetooth, etc.) in device manager and seeing how that affects the non-paged pool size after rebooting. I'd also try to make sure the drivers were current.

Comment: If it is a Samsung ultrabook, check [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/557979/windows-8-out-of-memory)

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Comment: Go to the Processes tab and sort by memory usage. Post a screenshot of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess what guys. It looks like there is no memory leak after all!

"Samsung" was generous enough to enhance my notebook with a tool called "IntelliMemory" which flew past my bloatware-radar because initially I thought this was related to "Ïntel". It "intelligently manages my cache allocating it to RAM" but actually I think it is crap and a memory hog, besides all storage is SSD anyway.

Peace.

Comment: It is also pointlessly duplicating the [Superfetch](http://www.osnews.com/story/21471/) feature in Windows that does exactly the same thing. Windows does not actually allocate memory to do it, it simply shows up as "cached" and is ready to be flushed if needed. I currently have 2.8G "in-use" and 9G "cached".

Comment: "IntelliMemory" should be disabled. The vendor claims to have a fix that tames its nonpaged pool usage, but why bother? As Mokubai said, Windows already has SuperFetch, and it is often not just pointless but actively harmful to have more than one file cache mechanism working at the same time (they tend to compete with each other for memory, disk I/O bandwidth, etc.).